# Log4j2 OnStartupTriggeringPolicy declaration in properties file

Tags: log4j2

I know how declare OnStartupTriggeringPolicy element in xml file as below.

But in our project we are using properties file. I don't know how to define it in properties file. 
Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking at the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties), if you wanted to add that triggering policy to the RollingFileAppender just do

```
appender.rolling.policies.startup.type = OnStartupTriggeringPolicy
```